# How to use catalina.sh to run on boot?

Tags: tomcat

Sir
I have an ERP, which runs catalina on tomcat. to run this i need java to be installed. Now my JAVA_HOME is usr/bin/java but i have a catalina.sh script which i want to run on boot. to do that i added the catalina.sh file in rc.local. but when the system boots it says JAVA_HOME variable needs to be declared. for that program it uses java from a different location.

for example:
i need to run the file from:
/home/ambee/jakarta/catalina.sh
to run this file i need to show the java_home to:
/home/ambee/jakarta/java
but the system doesn't look for that on booting it goes to the default location of /usr/bin/java

Please give me a solution if possible.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"` to the top of the file if you must use your script in rc.local,

A better alternative is to add `. /path/to/yourscript.sh` in the /etc/init.d/tomcat script under the start call, this literally includes your sh script.

From there just run with `chkconfig tomcat5 on` to start the services post boot.

Note however updates to tomcat that update the init.d script may break this change and you will want to move your script out of a home directory and into somewhere like /usr/share